# How to access a private ELB URL in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-lambda

I have an ELB that is pointing HTTPS (443) - https://dummyendpint.com. This is in Private VPC and exposed to only whitelisted IP addresses.

Now I am working on this endpoint (https://dummyendpint.com) in AWS Lambda but I can't able to make my Lambda function reach the private endpoint. Is there any way to assign a static IP address to the Lambda function and make it whitelisted in ELB security Group or any other way to make my lambda access this private IP address?